# How to push a generated file from a node app to github repo?

Tags: node.js, github, nodegit

There will be a file created on some user action in node app. When the file is created , it should be pushed to a github repository to a specific branch.
I have tried using simple-git but not able to achieve it.

This is for a node app in which a file will be created on some user action.
I have tried to reach the remote repository from the node but ended up in some errors.

Comment: which errors show up when you try to push to the remote repository? `git add <filename> && git commit -m 'new node file' && git push` should work unless your local branch is behind the remote

Comment: I'm trying to use simple-git library to do all the git related works. https://github.com/steveukx/git-js

Comment: I want to configure it and push the file to the github repository using its url.